# Is NullWritable an acceptable input key for mappers?

Tags: hadoop

I'm writing a custom recordReader that outputs key-value pairs to my mapper. I really only need to output values and don't need keys, so I was planning on using a NullWritable for my key and a Text for my value.

I'm essentially using a WholeFileInputFormat, as exampled in this book which also uses NullWritable keys: [book link](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Nff49D7vnJcC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=hadoop+the+definitive+guide+whole+file+recordreader+source&source=bl&ots=IigyRo7uVv&sig=X7XbbDDoAYwYj9IBFgghp7k_EYA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cfr0UPbFO8io0AGR14D4Cg#v=onepage&q=hadoop%20the%20definitive%20guide%20whole%20file%20recordreader%20source&f=false)

However, looking at the default hash partitioner hadoop uses, I don't see how this wouldn't send every record to the same mapper:

```
public class HashPartitioner<K, V> extends Partitioner<K, V> {
    public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
    }
}
```

Since NullWritable has the same hashCode, it seems like only one mapper would process all the data. It seems like there should be a way to make hadoop split up all the records evenly without having to come up with your own key.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm talking about **k1** in the standard hadoop format:
(k1, v1) -> map (k2, v2) -> combine -> (k2, v2) -> reduce -> (k3, v3) (output)

Comment: I think you waned to say Reducer instead of Mapper. Only one Reducer will you data. Because Mappers are decided based on the number of data blocks. Practitioner comes into picture after map job. Please clarify??

Comment: I am talking about Mappers (edited post for clarity). Does the partitioning only happen between mappers and reducers then? How does the InputFormat divide data among mappers then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of mapper for you job will depend on how you override *getSplits* method from *FileInputFormat* abstract class (*InputFormat* interface). There will be only one mapper for *WholeFileInputFormat*, because it return ***false*** in *isSplitable*. The *getSplits* from *FileInputFormat* uses the *isSplitable* method to check whether input is splitable or not and create input splits which gets assigned to Mappers.

You can check the implementation of *getSplits* from [*FileInputFormat*](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.19.1-hudson-3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.java#FileInputFormat.getSplits%28org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf%2Cint%29) for more details.

There is no role of Partitioner for deciding the number of Mapper. The role of Partitioner is to send the same hashed keys to the same Reducer. If you output *NullWritable* as key from Mapper then all the key will go to single Reducer.

**Update:**
The number of Mappers not essentially be the number of files. HDFS stores the data into blocks. So if HDFS block size is 128MB and file size is 256MB, then it can have two splits which will be passed to two different Mappers. That is why, *isSplitable* comes into the picture whether particular file is splitable or not.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So that means that if I have n files there will be n input splits (since input is not splitable). I assume hadoop just automatically evenly divides these input splits among available mappers?